# Using Opus with PortAudio

Tags: c++, c, portaudio, opus

I'm having trouble for using opus with Port audio. 
I need to read data audio from a stream using PortAudio, encoding data, decoding data and writing data. If I just read and write, everything works well. But when encoding and decoding, all I can hear is snow with my voice in background.
Here a part of my code:

I/O stream header:

```
#define NUM_CHANNELS    (2)
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paInt24
#define SAMPLE_RATE  (48000)
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER (1024)
#define SAMPLE_SIZE (3)
#define FRAME_SIZE (960)

class                           SoundSystem
{

 private:
  PaStream                      *_stream;
  int                           _readBufferSize;
  PaStreamParameters            _inputParam;
  PaStreamParameters            _outputParam;
  unsigned char                         *_readBuffer;

 public:
  SoundSystem();
  ~SoundSystem();

  // Init Stream                                           
  bool                          initPa();
  bool                          openStream();
  bool                          startStream();
  bool                          initStream();

  // Init params stream                                    
  bool                          initParams() const;
  bool                          initInputParams();
  bool                          initOutputParams();
  bool                          initParams();

  // I/O                                                   
  bool                          writeOnStream(unsigned cha\
r *buff);
  bool                          readFromStream();

  // Utils                                                 
  void                          cleanReadBuffer();
  int                           getReadBufferSize() const;
  unsigned char                 *getReadBuffer() const;

};
```

I/O stream .cpp:

```
SoundSystem::SoundSystem()
{
  _stream = NULL;
  _readBufferSize = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * NUM_CHANNELS * SAMPLE_SIZE;
  _readBuffer= new unsigned char [_readBufferSize];
}

SoundSystem::~SoundSystem()
{
}

bool            SoundSystem::initPa()
{
  if ((Pa_Initialize()) != paNoError)
    return (false);
  return (true);
}

bool            SoundSystem::openStream()
{
  if ((Pa_OpenStream(&_stream, &_inputParam, &_outputParam, SAMPLE_RATE,
                     FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, paClipOff, NULL, NULL)) != paNoError)
    return (false);
  return (true);
}

bool            SoundSystem::startStream()
{
  if ((Pa_StartStream(_stream)) != paNoError)
    return (false);
  return (true);
}

bool            SoundSystem::initStream()
{
  if ((openStream()) == false)
    std::cerr << "can not open stream" << std::endl;
  if ((startStream()) == false)
    std::cerr << "cannot start stream" <<std::endl;
  return (true);
}

bool            SoundSystem::initParams()
{
  if ((initPa()) == false)
    std::cerr << "can not ijnit PA" << std::endl;
  initInputParams();
  initOutputParams();
  return (true);
}

bool            SoundSystem::initInputParams()
{
  if ((_inputParam.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice()) == paNoDevice)
    return (false);
  _inputParam.channelCount = 2;
  _inputParam.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
  _inputParam.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(_inputParam.device)->defaultLowInputLatency;
  _inputParam.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
  return (true);
}

bool            SoundSystem::initOutputParams()
{
  if ((_outputParam.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice()) == paNoDevice)
    return (false);
  _outputParam.channelCount = 2;
  _outputParam.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
  _outputParam.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(_outputParam.device)->defaultLowInputLatency;
  _outputParam.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
  return (true);
}

bool            SoundSystem::writeOnStream(unsigned char *buff)
{
  if ((Pa_WriteStream(_stream, buff, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)) != paNoError)
    {
      std::cout << "FAIL WRITE" <<std::endl;
      return (false);
    }
  return (true);
}

bool            SoundSystem::readFromStream()
{
  if ((Pa_ReadStream(_stream, _readBuffer, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)) != paNoError)
    return (false);
  return (true);
}

void            SoundSystem::cleanReadBuffer()
{
  for (int i = 0; i != _readBufferSize; i++)
    _readBuffer[i] = 0;
}

int             SoundSystem::getReadBufferSize() const
{enter code here
  return (_readBufferSize);
}

unsigned char*          SoundSystem::getReadBuffer() const { return (_readBuffer); }
```

Encode header:

```
#define FRAME_SIZE (960)
#define SAMPLE_RATE (48000)
#define CHANNELS (2)
#define APPLICATION OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP

#define MAX_FRAME_SIZE (6*960)

class                           EncoderSystem
{

 private:
  OpusEncoder                   *_encode;
  OpusDecoder                   *_decode;

  opus_int16                    _in[FRAME_SIZE*CHANNELS];
  opus_int16                    _out[MAX_FRAME_SIZE*CHANNELS];
  int                           _nbBytes;


 public:
  EncoderSystem();
  ~EncoderSystem();

  bool                          encoderCreate();
  bool                          decoderCreate();

  unsigned char*                encode(unsigned char *, int);
  unsigned char*                decode(unsigned char *, int);

  int                           getEncodeLen() const;

};
```

Encode .cpp:

```
EncoderSystem::EncoderSystem()
{
}

EncoderSystem::~EncoderSystem()
{
}

bool            EncoderSystem::encoderCreate()
{
  int           error;

  if ((_encode = opus_encoder_create(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNELS, OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP, &error)) == NU\
LL)
    {
      std::cerr << "Can not create encode" <<std::endl;
      return (false);
    }
  return (true);
}

bool            EncoderSystem::decoderCreate()
{
  int           error;

  if ((_decode = opus_decoder_create(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNELS, &error)) == NULL)
    {
      std::cerr << "Can not create decoder" <<std::endl;
      return (false);
    }
  return (true);
}

unsigned char*          EncoderSystem::encode(unsigned char *data, int size)
{
  unsigned char         *c_bits = new unsigned char [size];

  memcpy(_in, data, size);

  /* Encode the frame. */
  _nbBytes = opus_encode(_encode, _in, FRAME_SIZE, c_bits, size);
  if (_nbBytes<0)
    {
      std::cerr << "cannot decode" << std::endl;
      return NULL;
    }
  return (c_bits);
}
unsigned char*          EncoderSystem::decode(unsigned char *data, int size)
{

  int   frame_size = opus_decode(_decode, data, size, _out,
                                 MAX_FRAME_SIZE * CHANNELS * 2, 0);
  unsigned char         *pcm_bytes = new unsigned char [MAX_FRAME_SIZE * CHANNELS * 2];

  if (frame_size<0)
    {
      std::cerr << "cannot decode" << std::endl;
      return (NULL);
    }
memcpy(pcm_bytes, _out, size);

  return (pcm_bytes);
}

int             EncoderSystem::getEncodeLen() const { return (this->_nbBytes); }
```

I really need you, thanks a lot to take your time to help me.

Comment: Not really sure what the issue is but you potentially have a couple of large memory leaks in EncoderSystem::encode and EncoderSystem::decode - you don't free the buffers you allocated.  This is also a performance issue - it would be better to allocate the buffers once as required (or if they need to grow).
You may be better off having an encode/decode stream that you can push audio data into that also handles the situation where the number of audio samples is not an exact multiple of the frame size.

Answer (score 1):

> `#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paInt24`

That's probably your problem. As far as I know the standard OPUS codecs take 16-bit integers or 32-bit floating point samples. These correspond to the PortAudio sample types paInt16 and paFloat32.

I recommend getting the types of all your sample buffers correct. Using unsigned char* for formatted sample data is asking for trouble. You need to understand what data types are expected by PortAudio functions and by the OPUS codec functions.